# x++ ax 2012 creating element prefix

Tags: xml, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I am exporting data from ax into xml.  I want to export the data so there is a prefix such as `<pidx:whatever> whatever </pidx:whatever>`

The sample output should look like this.

But in x++ there is 3 options to create elements.  `createelement`, `createlement2` and `createelement3` which requires a namespace so I have to do `xmldoc.createelemenet3("pidx", "whatever", "somenamespace")`  is there a way to exclude the namespace? or does it make an impact on the output if the desired output doesn't have a namespace

Comment: why not just try it out?

Comment: Did you take a look at [Create XML node with prefix but no namespace](https://dynamicsuser.net/ax/f/developers/74368/create-xml-node-with-prefix-but-no-namespace)?

Comment: thanks that worked